# Convergence of an improper integral.

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

$$\int_{-1}^1\sin\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2}\,dx$$
I've tried Abel and Dirichlet tests but it doesn't seem to be that easy. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried to work out so far?

Comment: how about $t=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=x+1$. Then, as $t\to 0^+$,
$$\sin\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2}
=\sin\left(\frac{t}{2-t}\right)\frac{1}{t^2(2-t)^2}\sim
\frac{t/2}{4t^2}=\frac{1}{8t}$$
and may we conclude that the integral over $(-1,a]$ is divergent when $-1<a<1$ .

Moreover, if we restrict the integral over $[a,1)$ with $-1<a<1$, then by letting $t=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$, we get 
$$\int_{a}^1\sin\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2}\,dx=
\frac{1}{8}\int_{b}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin\left(t\right)(t+1)^2}{t^2}\,dt=\\
\frac{1}{8}\int_{b}^{+\infty}\left(\sin(t)+\frac{2\sin(t)}{t}+\frac{\sin(t)}{t^2}\right)\,dt$$
where $b=\frac{a+1}{a-1}>0$, which is not convergent because $\frac{\sin(t)}{t}$ and $\frac{\sin(t)}{t^2}$ are integrable over $[b,+\infty)$, whereas $\int_b^r\sin(t)\,dt$ is not convergent as $r\to +\infty$.

Comment: Yes that's true but what about the case when t->2? I think that's what made me struggle.

Comment: If the integral diverges near $-1^+$, then it is not convergent no matter its behaviour near $1^-$.